# How to use SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) from Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-ce

I want to access Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition databases from Java. How can I do that? I searched for JDBC driver for SQLCE, but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a newsgroup post sent this Tuesday (2008-12-09) by Jimmy Wu@Mircrosoft](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.jdbcdriver/browse_thread/thread/2ba56d70e6b35ee7):

> The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver
>   does not support connecting to SQL 
>   Server Compact.  At this time there
>   isn't a scheduled JDBC support for SQL
>   Server Compact edition.  Thank-you for
>   your continuing support of SQL 
>   Server.
>
> Sincerely,  Jimmy Wu

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=770916&SiteID=1), there isn't one and there aren't any plans neither.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with SQL Server CE, I presume that MS provides an ODBC driver for it. Although it is not recommended for production use, you can use the JDBC-ODBC bridge to make your connection.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:<yourODBC_DSN>");
```

*To reiterate, the JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver provided with JDBC is recommended only for development and testing, or when no other alternative is available.*

Comment: No, there is no ODBC driver for SQL Server CE, and there are apparently no plans for one.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the **SqlJDBC4** library. I know a coworker uses it.

Comment: From reading the MS site it seems that it does not support SQL CE.

Answer (score -1):

Good tutorial [sqljdbc-tut](http://www.herongyang.com/jdbc/sqljdbc-jar-Microsoft-JDBC-Driver.html)

Latest driver (in tech preview) is [sqljdbc-jars](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F914793A-6FB4-475F-9537-B8FCB776BEFD&displaylang=en)