# JDBC connection to remote server without installing SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

Say I have a small inventory based software in Java connected to a SQL Server database. SQL server is not installed on that place where it is to be deployed and those people hav nothing to do with databases. We know that it takes a lot of time to install SQL Server. 
Simply speaking, I need a light software which can be installed easily and provide JDBC connectivity to my Java application.

Comment: What does this mean "provide JDBC connectivity to my Java application"? JDBC connection is related to connection with database server but not your application. You need to specify why don't you use JDBC direct in your application.

Comment: YOu can download the SQLServer JDBC client from Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an embedded version of [java Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html). It runs inside the JVM and does not need installation.

This works assuming of course that the you're not trying to connect to a common database across different client instances. Each instance runs it's own Derby and persists data to a persistence store.

Comment: Will try this for sure. Any similar solution for C# ?

Comment: With regret I must admit that C# is not part of my armory. A related question on SO sheds some light on the matter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c

Comment: @Gagan93 SQL Server is capable of the same thing.

Comment: The last time I checked [JDBC could not connect to CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358318/how-to-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-from-java). Has that changed now ?