# which embedded db supports TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, spring-batch, spring-test

I have a spring batch application which reads data from SQL server. I would like to write an integration test against an embedded db which supports TSQL.

Exp: My main application has some queries which uses "for json path"

I am looking for an embedded db where I can test in memory.

PS: I tried H2 and looks like it does not support TSQL.

Comment: I found a relation between SQL Server Compact and T-SQL in some documentation I viewed.

Comment: Thanks @MaxVoisard. It seems its deprecated.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

Comment: Yep, support ends in July 2021...I can't seem to find any other DBMS that supports T-SQL on Wikipedia, however...not even MongoDB or SQLite

Answer (score 3):

Please download this
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is a free, embedded database that software developers can use for building ASP.NET websites and Windows desktop applications. SQL Server Compact 4.0 has a small footprint and supports private deployment of its binaries within the application folder, easy application development in Visual Studio and WebMatrix, and seamless migration of schema and data to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

FYI -

Looks like Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver does not support connecting to SQL 
Server Compact.

[How to use SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358318/how-to-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-from-java)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d25a17f-6dda-4bec-8a92-f068594553ef/java-and-sql-server-compact-edition?forum=sqlce

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb).

I do not know about its technical details, however. I have personally not (yet) used it in a development project. Perhaps it cannot be considered to be an embedded database like SQL Server Compact Edition is. But a quick search on Internet does indicate that it could be accessed from/with Java.

Regarding managing LocalDB databases with SQL Server Management Studio... Contrary to what is stated in the official documentation, I did succeed to connect to LocalDB using SSMS (version 18.9.1). I only needed to enter `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` as the server name in the connection dialog and use Windows Authentication.